# Displaying images using custom ListView Filter in Android

Tags: android, listview, search, filtering

I have created a list view in android and implemented custom filtering method, but images in the list view are not corresponding to text after using filter. This is because it filters only namesList list. I need to filter both namesList and imagesList at the same time. How do I do that?

```
public class MyCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {


private final Activity context;
private List<String> filterList;
private List<String> namesList;
private List<String> imagesList;

public CustomList(Activity context,List<String> namesList, List<String> imagesList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, namesList);
    this.context = context;
    this.namesList = namesList;
    this.imagesList = imagesList;
    this.filterList= namesList;

}
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return namesList.size();
}
@Override
public String getItem(int pos){
    return namesList.get(pos);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int pos){
    return namesList.indexOf(getItem(pos));
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    txtTitle.setText(namesList.get(position));
    imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(imagesList.get(position), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));


    return rowView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            namesList = (List<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            namesList = filterList;
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                List<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList <String>();

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i <namesList.size(); i++) {
                    String dataNames = namesList.get(i);
                    if (dataNames.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {

                        FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);

                    }
                }

                results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());
            } else {
                results.count = namesList.size();
                results.values = namesList;
            }


            return results;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code with this:

```
List<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList <String>();
List<String> FilteredArrayImages = new ArrayList <String>();

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i <namesList.size(); i++) {
                String dataNames = namesList.get(i);
                String images = imagesList.get(i);
                if (dataNames.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {

                    FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                    FilteredArrayImages.add(images);

                }
            }
```

Then return this two List as a `FilterResults` object.

Comment: How do I return two lists at once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example
Working for me
MainActivity

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        postArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Dummy Title", "Dummy Sub Title"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Searchview in actionbar", "enjoy search functionality from actionbar in android"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Search in listview", "search feature that filter listview item"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Android Search Bar", "adding search feature in toolbar using appcompat library"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Android Studio SearchView example", "Android SearchView tutorial in android studio"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("Android Tutorial", "Get latest android material with simple solution"));
        postArrayList.add(new Post("nkDroid tutorials", "A to Z Android tutorials at one place"));


        myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(postArrayList, SearchActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        //*** setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener ***
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {
                myAppAdapter.filter(searchQuery.toString().trim());
                listView.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when expanded
                return true;  // Return true to expand action view
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Adapter Example

```
public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle, txtSubTitle;


    }

    public List<Post> parkingList;

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> arraylist;

    public MyAppAdapter(List<Post> apps, Context context) {
        this.parkingList = apps;
        this.context = context;
        arraylist = new ArrayList<Post>();
        arraylist.addAll(parkingList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return parkingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, null);
            // configure view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.txtSubTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle() + "");
        viewHolder.txtSubTitle.setText(parkingList.get(position).getPostSubTitle() + "");
        return rowView;


    }

    public void filter(String charText) {

        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        parkingList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            parkingList.addAll(arraylist);

        } else {
            for (Post postDetail : arraylist) {
                if (charText.length() != 0 && postDetail.getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    parkingList.add(postDetail);
                } 
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Post

```
public class Post {

    private String postTitle;

    private String postSubTitle;

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
    }

    public String getPostSubTitle() {
        return postSubTitle;
    }

    public void setPostSubTitle(String postSubTitle) {
        this.postSubTitle = postSubTitle;
    }

    public Post(String postTitle, String postSubTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.postSubTitle = postSubTitle;
    }
}
```